# display Loader while api is fetching data using react-router-dom, defer, useLoaderData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Loader loads for a fraction of a second only, in case there is a delay in API response, I have attached a screen recording for your reference.

Is there any way I can display the loader from the moment the API is called inside of `React.Suspense` itself? Attached is a screen recording

[image]

Following is my source code.

main.jsx

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, defer, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Homepage />,
    loader: async ({ request, params }) => {
      const data = await  fetch('https://api.rapidmock.com/mocks/j4CMM', {
        headers : {
          "x-rapidmock-delay": 2500
        }
      });
      
      return defer({
        results: data.json(),
      });
    },
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLoaderData, Await, useAsyncValue } from "react-router-dom";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import "./App.css";

const Homepage = () => {
  const { results } = useLoaderData();

  // Render the data when it is available
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading data...</p>}>
      <Await
        resolve={results}
        errorElement={<p>Error loading data</p>}
        
      >
        
        {(results) => {
          console.log("results", results);
          return <>Hello</>;
        }}
      </Await>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that if you want to *actually* ***defer*** the loader data then you shouldn't be awaiting anything in the loader function, just return the promise.

See [deferred](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred).

The "ah-ha" moment came when I read this section in the docs:

> You can literally switch between whether something is going to be
> deferred or not based on whether you include the await keyword:
>
> ```
> return defer({
>   // not deferred:
>   packageLocation: await packageLocationPromise,
>   // deferred:
>   packageLocation: packageLocationPromise,
> });
> ```

When the `loader` is `async` and `awaits` anything at all this actually blocks the loader completing and blocks the route's element mounting and rendering. What you are seeing currently is the UI blocked while the `fetch` occurs, and *then* the route loads and ***only*** the `response.json` Promise was deferred/awaited.

Return the entire Promise chain.

Example:

```js
loader: ({ request, params }) => {
  const results = fetch("https://api.rapidmock.com/mocks/j4CMM", {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidmock-delay": 2500
    }
  }).then((response) => response.json());

  return defer({ results });
}
```

[image: Edit display-loader-while-api-is-fetching-data-using-react-router-dom-defer-useload]

Comment: Criminally underrated answer. I would have never guessed that this was the case, I was so confused what I'm doing wrong. Basically in my case I use RTKQ unwrap and instead of returning the promise I was awaiting and returning the response. This is 100% correct - making the loader async blocks the component from mountain, so it never gets to the potential suspense await. Working example: `() => {
  const getItemsQuery = store.dispatch(api.endpoints.getItems.initiate());
  try {
    return defer({ items: getItemsQuery.unwrap() });
  } finally {
    getItemsQuery.unsubscribe();
  }
}`

Comment: @Nikolai Interesting approach to getting RTKQ endpoints working with RRD route loaders. 

Answer (score -1):

You can also make use of `navigation.state` as of React Router 6:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation#navigationstate

For example, If you have a route configuration with a loader:

```html
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    id: "root",
    loader: async () => {
      return getSomeData()
    },
    element: <HomePage />
  }
]);
```

you can make use of `navigation.state` in your home screen as:

```html
function HomePage() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
      
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        {navigation.state === "loading" ? <LoadingScreen /> : <Outlet />}
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: this will block the ui if you visit a page directly with a loader. ex. /home route has no route loader, /contactus route has a route loader. Visiting /home then clicking /contactus  Link will show a loading text and whatnot, work just fine. But Directly visiting  /contactus will block the UI until the loader completes.